# How to wrap text around image in BS placing text under image on mobile

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I have some text which is wrapped around an image. Is possible to place the text under the image when on a mobile device without using media queries. (Bootstrap classes only?)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

        <!-- image -->
        <figure class="figure float-left mr-3">
          <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-3 mx-auto d-block" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
          <figcaption>
            <h4 class="text-center mt-3">Kitten</h4>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!-- text -->
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum ......
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle I have created: https://jsfiddle.net/vh7m892z/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of BS utility classes in this instance.

Use `float-sm-left` on your `<figure>` element. Adjust as needed.

> See the [float](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/) documentation here.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

        <!-- image -->
        <figure class="figure float-sm-left mr-3">
          <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle mt-3 mx-auto d-block" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
          <figcaption>
            <h4 class="text-center mt-3">Kitten</h4>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!-- text -->
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum ......
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/bepar6o0/3/)

Also to get your desired styling just make use of a couple of additional BS classes.

`<figure class="figure d-block float-sm-left mx-auto mr-sm-3">`

See updated [Fiddle with a centred image](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/bepar6o0/4/).